# How to fill value in a limit_choices_to option in OneToOneField for Django Admin?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I need to limit the choices in a Django Admin form but cannot come up with a solution.  Given these models:

```
class ProductFamily(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    default_product_to_display = models.OneToOneField('Product', limit_choices_to={'product_family': ??????}) 
    # Enclosing Product reference in quotes is necessary since the Product declaration is below ProductFamily declaration

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True)
    product_family = models.ForeignKey(ProductFamily)
```

What should be placed in the ??????'s in class ProductFamily?  I've tried everything I can think of including name, 'name' ProductFamily, 'Product Family', self, self.id.  The options with self return an Internal Server Error.  The quoted options return: 'invalid literal for int()'.  When "name" is used unquoted, it returns:
 int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CharField'.
**If I put a hard-coded integer value in to test it, then it works fine, so it is obviously looking for an integer value.**
I also tried, without success, placing both 
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
in the declaration with id at the ??????'s as well as defining a function that returns self.id, but none of this works.

So - how do I limit the selection of products by showing only those whose product_family id's match those of the current ProductFamily?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a custom form to limit the queryset of the field, as trying to set `limit_choices_to` dynamically is super tough, if not completely impractical.

Example:

```
class ProductFamilyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self *args, **kwargs):
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
            self.fields['default_product_to_display'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(
                product_family=initial.product_family)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That almost got it, but the "initial.product_family" didn't work.  Here's what ultimately worked:

`class ProductFamilyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFamilyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.fields['default_product_to_display'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(product_family=self.instance.pk)

class ProductFamilyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductFamilyForm
   
    list_display = ('id','name','category','default_product_to_display',)  
    list_filter = ('category',)`

Comment: Well of course not :) That's a pseudo code example for you to provide your own value.